# Estimation from two observations

Tags: estimation, linear-dynamical-system

Suppose there are two vector signals $x$, $z$. The observer 1 receives a linear version of $x$ plus Gaussian noise. Observer 2 receives a linear sum of both $x$ and $z$ plus Gaussian noise as shown below;
$$y_1(t)=A_1(t)x(t)+n_1(t),$$
$$y_2(t)=A_2(t)x(t)+B_2(t)z(t)+n_2(t).$$
But observer 2 is only interested in estimating $z$ so ideally he would like to cancel the whole term $A_2x$. Furthermore $A_2$ is changing slowly over time. Slowly in the sense the changes are correlated over time.
Suppose observer 1 can provide his estimates of $x$ say $x_1$ to observer 2. Is there any way for observer 2 to use that information to better estimate $z$?
The matrices $A_1,A_2,B_2$ are independent.

Edit:
Suppose $A_2(t+1)= \sum_{n=0}^{n=t}\alpha_nA_2(n) + z_t(t+1)$ where $z_(t)$ are independent Gaussian noise.

Comment: (1) One would think that the answer would depend on *how* Observer 1 is estimating $x(t)$ and how good those estimates are.  (2) It seems you must assume more about $A_1, A_2$, and $B_2$, for otherwise the $x(t)$ and $z(t)$ will not be identifiable.  In particular, you need some specific *quantitative* assumptions; "changing slowly over time" is not really amenable to useful analysis.

Comment: @whuber I created this problem out of a practical situation I have in my experiment. Could you please suggest such assumptions? I am not sure how to put "changing slowly" into sold equation. What I mean is $A_2(t)$ and $A_2(t+1)$ are different but are correlated. I will include my idea in a edit of the question. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not, at least not using the formulas given.